# Android - Unity3D 5 : CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources

Tags: android, unity3d, java

Al momento de dar al boton de build en unity3d 5, empieza el proceso normal, y a la mitad tira el error. Esto es lo que dice la consola:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
>   C:\Users\Walther\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.0-preview\aapt.exe
>   package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S
>   "res" -I
>   "C:/Users/Walther/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar"
>   -F bin/resources.ap_
>
> stderr[
>
> ] stdout[
>
> ] UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
>   psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit
>   waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.TasksCommon.Exec
>   (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir,
>   System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.CompileResources
>   (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.Execute
>   (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks
>   (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Comment: Por favor, agrega una explicación de lo que intentas hacer y tu codigo, simplemente es imposible saber que preguntas.

Comment: @MaxSandoval Disculpa, ya mejoré algo la redacción. El error es al dar build.

Comment: Agrega la ubicación de tu Mamifest.xml y su contenido.

Answer (score 0):

Primero verifica que JAVA se encuentre en tus variables de entorno.

> JAVA_HOME
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin

Después intenta esto:

Abre el SDK Manager y borra todas las SDK (preview)tools e instala la ultima que no sea preview, al parecer es un error con las herramientas de compilación de Android 24.0.0 preview